# password_verify() returns false using password_compat library

Tags: php, passwords, bcrypt

```
<?php
$hash = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
echo $hash;
if (password_verify('rasmuslerdorf', $hash)) {
    echo 'Password is valid!';
} else {
    echo 'Invalid password.';
}
?>
```

Above is my code on hashing password using bcrypt. Everytime I refresh my browser, the $hash returns different results, which I think it's normal because crypt() function does that too.

However, I don't understand why the result returns 'Invalid Password' when comparing using password_verify() function. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong because I'm following the guide here [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php) using this library : https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

My php version is 5.4.x... I've included the password_compat library.

Comment: the different hash return is intended, do you get the same result if you set it like so: $hash = password_hash("rasmuslerdorf", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

Comment: Ok, the code above suddenly works... I'm not sure what really happened. I think cache problem, I'm not sure. And PASSWORD_BCRYPT works.

Comment: I am getting the same issue

Comment: try doing echo PASSWORD_DEFAULT; There is a chance that it is not PASSWORD_BCRYPT and it's generating a hash with time or random data, thus making it change every time.